# Estimate values below the limit of detection from a left-censored dataset

Tags: survival, maximum-likelihood, minitab, interval-censoring

I have 32/180 determinations of a laboratory marker below the limit of detection (LOD) and would like to estimate them by maximum likelihood estimation. By using Minitab's reliability / survival analysis I was able to find a well-fitting model (lognormal) and to estimate mean, SD, and percentiles. How can I estimate the single missing values that are below the LOD? Is it OK to just use the percentiles for the first 32 values (up to the 17.77th percentile)?

Comment: Without additional information (that is, covariates for each determination) it is impossible to estimate specific values. That is because your estimation method assumes the data are *independent*. That implies there is no basis to assign different values to different less-than-LOD results.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, now I ran multiple imputation to determine the missing below-LOD-values.